# How to allow both types single number and array of numbers from set of numbers in @hapi/joi?

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

There are two possibilities:

```
// 1) Pssibility - Any number from 1 to 3
activeStatus: 1 or 2 or 3

// 2) Possibility - Array of numbers, Any from 1, 2, 3
activeStatus: [1, 2, 3]
```

> I want to combine both possibilities and need to allow to enter any from single number or array of numbers,

Achieved, allow single number from 1 to 3,

```
activeStatus: Joi.number().valid(1, 2, 3)
```

Achieved, allow any type either its number or array using `any()`,

```
activeStatus: Joi.any().valid(1, 2, 3)
```

I tried adding array in `valid()`, but it sends an error,

```
activeStatus: Joi.any().valid(1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3])
// Method no longer accepts array arguments: valid'
```

Is there other way to achieve both possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
activeStatus: Joi.alternatives(
    Joi.number().valid(1, 2, 3),
    Joi.array().items(Joi.number().valid(1, 2, 3))
)
```